# What amplifier circuit to use for a wheatstone bridge force transducer

Tags: amplifier, signal, processing, load

I would like to amplify the signal from a force transducer which can measure load from 0-1500g. The object i am using is less than 1 gram. I would need an operational amplifier. I would like to know the other parameters to be taken into account in choosing the amplifier. Any help would much appreciated.  The transducer is from the [Honeywell FSS series](http://sensing.honeywell.com/fss-smt%20series%20force%20sensors)

Comment: Not nearly enough detail. Which specific force transducer? What supply rails will you be using? What bandwidth do you need?

Comment: Clearly we need more information.  You can't design a amplifier if you don't know the naure of the signals going in and what you want out.

Comment: Sorry for that i am still a novice in this field. I am actually using the following force transducer.http://docs-asia.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/0d25/0900766b80d25464.pdf

Comment: Basically I would need the voltage signal obtained with respect to time(decaying shown) when a drop of water hit the force transducer.

Comment: Before you can think about selecting an op-amp, you have to select a transducer. Will this transducer even be able to measure a force that small, or will the resulting signal be entirely buried in the noise?

Comment: Actually I need to use the above-mentioned transducer as it has already been bought. Is it possible to use this one and how to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

The question implies that you are trying to measure 1g with a force sensor capable of measuring 0-1500g.

Read its datasheet.
Its repeatability is 0.2% of span - about 3 grams error each time you make a measurement.
Its sensitivity shift with temperature changes is 5% of span - about 75 times as much as you are trying to weigh.
Its sensitivity is 2.4mV/V/N. So a 1g weight will measure 0.24millivolt with 10 volt excitation.

With this sensor, you are unlikely to be able to tell if a 1g weight is even there or not.
You either need a more suitable sensor or a bigger weight.

Comment: he's not weighing it, but measuring the impulse..  An accelerometer may be a better sensor.

Comment: I don't see how you infer that from the question. Oh - one of the comments refers to a drop of water? That isn't going to transfer its impulse to the sensor very effectively, and 1g is an overestimate of its mass. I think I'd be looking at a microphone - maybe a low cost piezo disc.

Comment: @Brian Drummond you wrote "Its sensitivity is 2.4mV/V/N. So a 1g weight will measure 0.24 millivolt with 10 volt excitation." I have a question though. 1 N is 101.97 gram-force which means 1 N is the gravitational force applied to 101.97 gr mass or 100 gr mass?  Is 1 N = 100 gr or 101.97 gram?

Comment: 1N (unit of force) is neither 100grams nor 101.97 grams (which are units of mass) and "gram-force" is (AFAIK) not a recognised SI unit. If gram-force means "the force exerted by this planet on a 1g mass" then, since the force of gravity varies in different places, it's not a very useful unit. I'm curious where you've seen it used...

Answer (score 0):

Since the sensor in question is an unpowered wheatstone bridge, you must provide a stable reference voltage and amplify the difference signal.  Here is a good tutorial on the design of a [bridge amplifier](http://masteringelectronicsdesign.com/measure-a-wheatstone-bridge-sensor-signal-with-an-adc/)